# Change textview background color width

Tags: java, android, background, textview

I have a problem that I explain better with this images:

Now I have this:

[image: what I have]

But I want this:

[image: what I want]

I want to have the background color of my textview stretch on all the width of the screen, but I don't know how to do it. Can someone help me?

Thanks! :)

Comment: On your XML do textview width="match_parent" solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `match_parent` as the width :

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: `android:gravity="center"` is also needed.

Comment: Sorry I forgot @arol_123, thank you for correcting me ;)